# Invoke copy paste for QgraphicsTextItem

Tags: qt

How can the cut, copy paste slots be invoked for QgraphicsTextItem. Though the the text editor has default slots for cut, copy and paste, but I don't know how to invoke them.

I have class that is inherited from QgraphicsTextItem. The use of this class is to add a text in GraphicsView. Now I want the cut, paste and copy functality for it. How can I go for that?

drawText.h

```
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QPen>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QFocusEvent;
class QGraphicsItem;
class QGraphicsScene;
class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class mText : public QGraphicsTextItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    mText( int, QGraphicsItem *parent=0 );
    enum { Type = UserType + 5 };
    int type() const;
    int id;

signals:
    void lostFocus(mText *item);
    void selectedChange(QGraphicsItem *item);


protected:
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

};
```

.cpp

```
#include "mtext.h"

mText::mText( int i, QGraphicsItem *parent)
    : QGraphicsTextItem(parent )
{
    //assigns id
    id = i;
}

int mText::type() const
{
    // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with text item.
    return Type;
}

QVariant mText::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
                                 const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged)
        emit selectedChange(this);
    return value;
}

void mText::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    emit lostFocus(this);
    QGraphicsTextItem::focusOutEvent(event);
}

void mText::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (textInteractionFlags() == Qt::NoTextInteraction)
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);

    QGraphicsTextItem::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: "the text editor has default slots" - what text editor are you referring to here?

Comment: Edited the post with code too.